# expire account if they have not logged in

Tags: php

I need to expire account after 3 months if they have not logged in to website. How can I automatically address in code to do it? How can I address to automatically delete user from database within three months in php language ?

Comment: Please provide (much) more details, as you currently seems to ask how do I create 'something' using 'something'. Which is very vague and impossible to answer. Show some (only) relevant code snippets, details of what is stored in your database, information of your system/website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options:

1. run a cron job that selects users that have not logged in 3 months, and marks their accounts as deleted (don't actually delete them IMHO, just maybe some residual data)
2. when a user logs in, check the last login time, and if it's greater than 3 months, return an error and force them to register.

Comment: it depends on why you need it and how you handle re-activation. hotmail/yahoo used to do this for ages. plus you can "ping" users this way randomly to lazy expire old ones without doing a mass delete. lazy expiration is far from "stupid".